# Is there a myth of someone living in the sun?

Tags: greek, mythical-creatures, myth-identification, sun

Is there a Greek myth of some sort of a god, human, or other creature living in the sun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as I know the Greco-Roman myths about the sun consistently refer to it as an object, usually the wheel of a chariot which is handled by Apollo or Helios. The Greeks didn't personify or anthropomorphize the sun.

Comment: Since "Helios" actually means "sun" in Greek I do not see how you can claim that "the Greeks didn't personify or anthropomorphize the sun". A very bad answer.

Comment: @fdb If you are aware of Greek myths which actually cite Helios *as* the sun and not the sun's charioteer, by all means post an answer and cite them. I'm happy to be proven wrong if you have sources.

Comment: Lots of sources here: http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=48179&context=lsj&action=hw-list-click

Comment: @fdb Forgive me, I don't read Greek — I have no idea what I'm looking at. If you could translate those and put them into context, make it an answer.

Comment: My point is very simply that "helios" is the Greek word for "sun". When used as a proper noun ("Helios") it is by definition a personification.

Comment: @fdb Sorry, we're talking past each other. The OP asked if the Greeks ever thought of the sun as a character/person/god/personality *itself*, the way they thought of the laurel tree as the person of Daphne, a river nymph. So far as I know, they thought of the sun as *the wheel of a chariot* driven by a god, originally named Helios; this task was later assigned to the god Apollo. Do any of the stories you link to describe Helios, himself, running or flying across the sky and glowing? That's what the OP is asking.

Comment: Do you know the Aesopic fable of the North Wind (Boreas) and the Sun (Helios)?

Comment: @fdb I don't. Please feel free to post a short summary and a link to a source as an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Perhaps you could research this yourself? It belongs pretty much to "common knowledge".

Answer (score 0):

The Hindu Mother goddess lives within the Sun thereby liberating the Sun's energy to the universe. Since then, this form of the Goddess has been known as Kushmanda, namely for her power and capability to live inside the Sun. The glow and radiance of her body are as luminous as that of the Sun.

source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navadurga